# Can someone break down exactly what a breadcrumb is and how to implement it?

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

Can someone break down exactly what a breadcrumb is and how to implement it?

```
<div class="breadcrumb"><a href="shirts.php">Shirts</a> &gt; <?php echo $product["name"]; ?></div>
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation): *"The graphical control element Breadcrumbs or breadcrumb trail is a navigation aid used in user interfaces. It allows users to keep track of their locations within programs or documents. The term comes from the trail of breadcrumbs left by Hansel and Gretel in the popular fairytale."*

Answer (score -1):

What a breadcrumb is:  you're locating a file on your computer, and the file is in your "Program Files" folder.  If you look on the explorer window you will see something like "  Computer  ->   C: Drive   ->   Program Files "   The "computer" and "C Drive" are breadcrumbs because their pieces of a path to get to a destination.

How to implement it:  Here's what I think is a helpful website for that:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4836/Breadcrumbs-in-ASP-NET